# Can't get .delay() working

Tags: jquery, delay

I have almost zero experience with jQuery so here it goes... I have already done a lot of research but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

I want two DIV's to fade in after each other, but with a delay between the first one and the second one. This is what I have so far:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $("div.1").hide();
        $("div.2").hide();
        $("div.1").fadeIn(400);
        $("div.2").delay(800).fadeIn(400);
});

</script>
<div class="1">
This is DIV1</div>
<div class="2">
This is DIV2</div>
```

I really hope you guys can help me out! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your code works, have you added jQuery to your page? http://jsfiddle.net/HLHuH/

Comment: Yes I have! Thanks for your help, I had jQuery 1.3 added to my website, pretty stupid.

Comment: Does the fade always take exactly 800 miliseconds? What happens in different browsers and machines, callbacks are much more solid approach

Comment: On behalf of @DiH "You have to remember that class names should not start with a digit. While some browsers are more forgiving than others, it's not a good practice to do it. Change classes' name to div1 and div2 and it should work well." :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [.delay method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) was added in jQuery 1.4, so if you were loading jQuery 1.3, as you indicate in a comment, then that's your problem. Your code should work correctly, as written, with 1.4 or later.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the callback functions so:

```
("div.1").fadeIn(400, function() {$("div.2").delay(800).fadeIn(400);});
```

in this way the fade in of `div.2` will fire **after** `div.1` `fadeIn` is complete

**without delay**

```
("div.1").fadeIn(400, function() {$("div.2").fadeIn(400);});
```

Comment: You actually don't have to, the call to `delay()` ensures the first animation has finished by the time the second one starts.

Comment: True, but I thought he wanted a gap between the first and second fade?

Comment: @Liam Which he already has. The first animation takes 400 milliseconds, the second one is delayed by 800 milliseconds, then takes a further 400 milliseconds. There should be a gap of roughly 400 milliseconds between the first ending and the second starting.